# Uncaught Attempting to create a component with an xtype that has not been registered :

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I've written a program in sencha, which worked fine. Since my files are getting too big, I am trying to split them into multiple small files using xtypes.

Basically, I am trying to have one main.js file calling an xtype list.js calling another xtype details.js also calling needed xtypes...

My problem is that since I've started to split my code, I am getting this error: `Uncaught Attempting to create a component with an xtype that has not been registered`.

I am sure that every single file is correctly link in my index.html.

Here is a sample of my code :

Details.js

```
var details = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
layout: 'card',
cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',

initComponent: function(){
    Ext.apply(this,{
        items:[]
    })
    details.superclass.initComponent.apply(this,arguments);
}
});
Ext.reg('details', details);
```

List.js

```
var Details = {xtype: 'details'};

var ListWrapper = new Ext.Panel({
id: "listwrapper",
layout: 'fit',
items: [List],
dockedItems: [homeTitleBar]
});

var Home = new Ext.Panel({
id: "home",
layout: 'card',
cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',
items: [ListWrapper, Details]
});

var HomeTab = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
iconCls: 'home',
title: 'Home',
layout: 'card',
initComponent: function() {
    Ext.apply(this,{
        items: [Home]
    }); 
    HomeTab.superclass.initComponent.apply(this,arguments);
}
});
Ext.reg('home', HomeTab);
```

Main.js

```
var menuBar = Ext.extend(Ext.TabPanel, {
layout: 'card',
cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',
fullscreen: true,
tabBar: {
    dock: 'bottom',
    layout: {pack: 'center'}
},
items:[
    {xtype: 'home'}
]
});
Ext.reg("menuBar", menuBar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the ordering of your `<script>` tags. It sounds like you are loading your files in the wrong order (maybe main.js before list.js or list.js before details.js).

I would also only use `Ext.reg` if you are going to be re-using your defined components, in your case it's looks like you are just using them once so there's not much to gain and you could just pass in the Component rather than a redundant extra `Object + xtype`